# Can a batch file handle SQLCMD error when :r file is not found?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a batch file calling SQLCMD to run a SQL script that tries to call a second script using :r

I need the batch file to be able to tell that SQLCMD could not find the file indicated by :r but even calling SQLCMD with -V1 (which should report all errors), checking "if errorlevel 1" returns false.

SQLCMD does print a message, but it's not generating an error return code.

test.bat:

```
@echo off
sqlcmd -E -S . -V1 -i test.sql
if errorlevel 1 goto :handleerror
echo All good.
goto :eof

:handleerror
echo An error occurred.
goto :eof
```

test.sql:

```
:r nonexistent.sql
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey there. I added the sample file contents. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace -V1 with -b